# Android Wear resource directory

Tags: android, android-layout, wear-os

I'd like an existing smartphone app to look good a smartwatch.
What is the correct  resource directory name for Wear layouts?

I tried `res/layout-wear`, but the console says that this resource directory name is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need an additional wearable module, which looks like a normal android projects, but it is only for wearable. You'll have `res/` too, where you will have only the layout of your wearable application. [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/index.html) you can find more info